# Timer inside a loop?

Tags: java, loops, timer

My program requires the result from inside an loop to be displayed or outputted with time intervals of 1000ms.
Is it possible to put the timer code:

```
 int delay2= 1000;
    final Timer timer2 = new Timer();
             timer2.schedule(new TimerTask(){
     public void run(){}

      },delay2, 1000);
```

Inside a loop to print an answer that is:

```
 System.out.println("dec2       "+deck2[g]);
       System.out.println("dec1       "+deck1[g]);
```

Between time intervals of 1000ms?

Thanks For Reading.

EDIT: Will this work?

```
final Timer timer2 = new Timer();
         timer2.schedule(new TimerTask(){
 public void run(){   
System.out.println("COUNT"+count);
for(int g = 0;g<e+1;g++)
 { 

   System.out.println("dec2       "+deck2[g]);
   System.out.println("dec1       "+deck1[g]);

}
} 
  },delay2, 1000);
```

EDIT2: Or This?

```
long t = new Date().getTime(); // time now in millies
do {
    for( g = 0;g<e+1;g++)
    {
    final long now = new Date().getTime();
    if( now - t >= 1000 ) {
System.out.println("dec2       "+deck2[g]);
 System.out.println("dec1       "+deck1[g]);
       t = new Date().getTime();  // reset reference time
    }
}
 count--;   
} while( count==0 );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [For loop inside a timer not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238830/for-loop-inside-a-timer-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the performance impact you can do something like this.

```
long t = new Date().getTime(); // time now in millies
do {
    // do something here
    // ...
    final long now = new Date().getTime();
    if( now - t >= 1000 ) {
       // do your logging
       // ...
       t = new Date().getTime();  // reset reference time
    }
} while( someCondition );
```

Comment: long t = new Date().getTime(); // time now in millies
do {
    for( g = 0;g<e+1;g++)
    {System.out.println("dec2       "+deck2[g]);
 System.out.println("dec1       "+deck1[g]);}
    final long now = new Date().getTime();
    if( now - t >= 1000 ) {

       t = new Date().getTime();  // reset reference time
    }
 count--;   
} while( count==0 );   I tried this but didn't work.Can you tell what i did wrong?..(im still learning java..)..

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  Are the loops terminating (what are the initial values of g and count)?

Comment: Initial value of g and count are zero.count gets incremented by another part of program until a value is reached.EDIT:I didn't understand the term"logging" what did u mean there?..The part where it says "do something here" i inserted the loop and the loop ends after the if(now-t>=1000) condition.The system.out.println statements are inside the the if(now-t>=1000).What did i do wrong here?...

Comment: I think you use System.out.println("dec2 "+deck2[g]); to debug your program. So logging is the process of writing some information to a stream like System.out or a log file.
Again, what do you mean by "not working"? What is the behavior of your program?

Comment: Ummm.The System.out.println("deck2"+deck2[g]); is an actual result statement that i need.Its is not intended for debugging.I am saying it is not working because I am not getting any result from that part that you gave.There is literally no output displayed in spite of me giving 2 statements to be Outputted in intervals of 1000 ms.i have updated my question.please read the EDIT2 part where i have used your code.Thanks.

Comment: You should check both loops for which values of count and g they are executed.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can make 'g' and instance variable and use it inside the run() method of the time to do what you want.

Something like:

```
private int g = 0;

private startTimer()
{
    final Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){  
           g++;                 // Incrementing the counter.
           System.out.println("dec2       "+deck2[g]);
           System.out.println("dec1       "+deck1[g]);

           // Stop the timer when done.
           if (g >= e + 1) timer.cancel();
        }
    }, delay, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Uhh i don't get you. Can You please Explain?